# Why is my vector logo pixelated around the edges

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, logo

I have created my first logo in Illustrator, I have just copied it to inDesign and the edges appear very pixelated. Can any anyone explain why that might be? I have created it in CMYK format.

Kind regard

Rob

Comment: Hey there R.Redford, welcome to GD.SE! It looks like you were able to answer your own question. You can either check the little box next to your answer to accept it, or delete this question (though leaving it up might help someone else down the line). If you have any questions about how the site works, have a look at the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or feel free to ping one of us in [Graphic Design Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) once your reputation reaches 20. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Thanks Vicki, although it looks better in Illustrator but now it still looks pixelated in Indesign for some reason

Comment: If you can edit your question to include some screenshots, someone might be able to better help you figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just discovered if you go to the Document Raster Effects Settings and select Anti-Alias this sorts it. :-) –

Comment: Keep in mind that, when you're working with the document, the software will render a very simplified version of the artwork to save space/processing power. You can change this behaviour with View > Display Performance. This viewing difference does not carry over to print or export, as the proper file is embedded at that point.

Comment: Apologies everyone for the delayed response, AMontpetit also answered my question when it came to InDesign. My logo displayed better in here once this setting was applied. Thank you